# How can I get specific results from a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm just learning angularjs and I'm strugling to get the results I want from this factory :

```
app.factory('foreCast', ['$http', function($http,$scope ) { 

var req = $http.jsonp("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/c1ab8xnw?&apikey=api-key&callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
     req.success(function (data) { 
         req.rows =data.results.collection1;
          req.rand =req.rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * req.rows.length)];
              console.log(req.rand); 
                 //i want this results      
                                       });    
return req; //how can i return req.rand?

}]);
```

Comment: try function($http) instead of function($http,$scope )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.factory('foreCast', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        getRand: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http
                .jsonp("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/c1ab8xnw?&apikey=api-key&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
                .then(function (response) {
                    var rows = response.data.results.collection1;
                    var rand = rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rows.length)];
                    deferred.resolve(rand);
                }, function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                })
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
}])
```

And then from controller for exemple use it like this :

```
foreCast.getRand().then(function(rand){
    var myRand = rand;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you never want to use the success handler with http. I believe its actually getting deprecated. The best practice is to use .then and .catch for errors. Secondly, most of the time you should be processing the result in your controller since the service is not supposed to know what to do with the data.

So that being said, we can trim down your factory a little bit.

```
app.factory('foreCast', ['$http', function($http,$scope ) { 
    var factory = {};
    factory.rand = function() {
        return $http.jsonp("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/c1ab8xnw?&apikey=api-key&callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
    };

    return factory;
}]);
```

Now in your controller:

```
app.controller('controller', ['foreCast', function(foreCast) {
    var self = this;

    foreCast.rand().then(function(response) {
        var rows = response.results.collection1;
        self.rand = rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rows.length)];
    });
}]);
```

now in your view just access this value with rand.

```
<div ng-bind="ctrl.rand"></div>
```